# How to Install SharePoint PowerShell Module inside C# for Azure Function App

Tags: c#, powershell, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

Just to manage expectations, I am new to PowerShell and to Azure Functions.

Since Azure Functions 2.x no longer supports PowerShell so I am trying to run my PowerShell scripts which requires SPO modules from C# (code below) I am having trouble running the Azure Function App because the PowerShell scripts needed the SPO modules. Anybody who knows how to install the needed modules inside C# PowerShell Instance like Runspace or anything the like? I am even on the right track here? Any comments is highly appreciated. Thank you all.

Sample Code:

```
 [FunctionName("TestFunction")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
        {
            using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                var script = @"
Install-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell
Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline

$url = '<SharePoint Url>'

$ListName = '<List Name>'

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $url -UseWebLogin 

$Fields = Get-PnPField -List $ListName  
$Items= Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -PageSize 5000

$RowCtr = 1;

foreach($item in $items.FieldValues)
{
    #do something
    $RowCtr++;
}
";

                PowerShellInstance.AddScript(script);

                var results = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();
                //some other codes
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Runspace within an Azure Function as shown in [this example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/blob/2942e616bdfadf3a41760505b480d5533a3348c4/src/WebJobs.Script/Description/PowerShell/PowerShellFunctionInvoker.cs#L81-L117), lines 93-98. For modules, you can include them as part of the payload you deploy to your function app (recommended), or install them using [Kudu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings#kudu).

Answer (score 1):

Once you upload your modules via the payload or Kudo, your script should work with a few modifications. The modules can be directly downloaded from the https://www.powershellgallery.com/ using Save-Module. 
After that, your script should work with a few modifications. According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/connect-pnponline?view=sharepoint-ps, -UseWebLogin is browser based. Alternatively, you can use the -Credentials parameter. Here is how you build a PSCredential object:

```
$secPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "StringPassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::new("userName", $secPasswd)
```

Update on 1/23/20:

**As of November 2019, PowerShell in Functions has GA-ed and it is available in Functions V2 and V3**, for more information, please visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell

To have your PowerShell function app install dependencies from the `https://www.powershellgallery.com/`, you can use our managed dependencies feature. For more info, please visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell#dependency-management.

Cheers,

Francisco