# Changing site collection administrator via powershell in azure function

Tags: azure, powershell, microsoft-graph-api, azure-functions, sharepoint-online

I created a workflow that provisions O365 groups via an azure function app which runs powershell (based off this code on [github](https://github.com/martinagrom/Ignite2018GroupsGovernanceToolkit/tree/master/f1-CreateGroup)). I noticed that the default site collection administrators are the owners of the created group. Most of the time i just want users to be able to invite more people to group but not create subsites etc..
For now I always have to change administrators manually. Is there any way to change the site collection administrators via powershell (or any other language) in an azure function?

I already tried to just execute Connect-SPOService and Set-SPOUser in the function but there is no such cmdlet in the context of the function.

Goal would be a to have some code/function to change site collection administrators via the microsoft graph api or some other means. Maybe it is possible to add the missing cmdlets where the function can access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use PowerShell modules within an Azure Function, you'll need to upload your modules to your function app, either by bundling them with your deployment or using Kudu. The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54361668/how-to-install-sharepoint-powershell-module-inside-c-sharp-for-azure-function-ap/54429917#54429917) from Francisco and myself could be helpful to you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll have to look into that to try it. Are there any additional permissions necessary to the ones given by the app registration?